# Is it possible to have a tab inside of a page in XamarinForm?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I typed "tab" and the only thing that seems to be relavent in the IntelliSense was "TabbedPage". I searched Google, and it also only showed tabbed page.

But what if I want something else above the tab? Something like this? Is this achievable in Xamarin Form? It is possible in native Android.

```
--------------------
Text inputs, buttons

---------------------

 tabbed or swipe-able
     content




--------------------
```

Comment: you can't use a true TabbedPage, but you can use something like a ToggleButton to create a tabbable UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabbedPage is a Page, is not a View so you can't include it inside another page.

On GitHub there is some TabView you can use. For example [XFControls](https://github.com/gruan01/XFControls/blob/master/XFControls/Documents/TabView.md)

```
  <ctrls:TabView.TabTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
        <ctrls:FontIcon Glyph="{Binding Glyph}"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource font}"
                        FontSize="25"
                        Color="Gray"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                      >
          <ctrls:FontIcon.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="ctrls:FontIcon"
                         Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                         Value="True"
                         >
              <Setter Property="Color" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </ctrls:FontIcon.Triggers>
        </ctrls:FontIcon>

        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
               TextColor="Gray"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               FontSize="10">

          <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                         Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                         Value="True"
                       >
              <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>

      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ctrls:TabView.TabTemplate>

  <ctrls:TabView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
             HorizontalOptions="Center" />          
    </DataTemplate>
  </ctrls:TabView.ItemTemplate>

</ctrls:TabView>
```